# Index for partial matching

Tags: sql, sql-server

Person table,

```
Id, Name, Phone
-----------------------
1,  abc,  12345678910
```

Once the phone number is always in 11 digits, and I added index for this column for searching.

But coming to international business, there would be international prefix for some phone numbers.

```
+86 12345678910
```

But when users do searching, they always just input the number -- without a prefix. So I have to rewrite the query from `phone=12345678910` to `phone like '%12345678910'`. I think  that would make the index losing its merit, right?

I think I should add a column for the prefix `+86`. How do you think about it?

Comment: You've answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searches like yours -- that would benefit from an index -- I typically perform two searches: a simple straight search and a reverse one. Both use an index, albeit a different one.

```
create table person (id int, name varchar(40), phone varchar(20));

insert into person (id, name, phone) values (1, 'abc', '12345678910');
insert into person (id, name, phone) values (2, 'def', '+86 12345678910');

create index ix1 on person (phone); -- for simple search

select * from person where phone = '12345678910';
```

Now, the reverse search:

```
alter table person add rev_phone as reverse(phone);
create index ix2 on person (rev_phone);

select * from person where rev_phone like reverse(concat('%', '12345678910'));
```

Or the combined search (both at the same time):

```
select * from person where phone = '12345678910';
union
select * from person where rev_phone like reverse(concat('%', '12345678910'));
```

Since the "straight" and "reverse" searches use indexes they are both blazing fast.